# How i can MenuButton's ContextMenu separated using css in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, drop-down-menu, contextmenu

I was searching about how to set co-ordinate of MenuButton's Context Menu in css and didn't find a way to achieve. I tryed do add css "top" but, this is did not worked. and after i tryed padding , this too did not worked.

***CSS***

```
.menu-button {
    -fx-background-color: #8400d4;
}

.root {
    -fx-background-color: #ba5555;
    -fx-padding: 10;
}

.context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: #006699;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-padding: 5em 0 0 0 ;
    top: 5em;
}

.menu-item .label {
    -fx-text-fill: #11534b;
}

.menu-item:focused .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

Example Picture :

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

so how i can do this? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-fx-translate-y` CSS property:

```css
.menu-button:openvertically .context-menu {
    -fx-translate-y: 20;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. this is worked for me. Last question, but how i can add in context menu triangle? Image link:  https://ibb.co/XCbxPpF

Comment: @ƏzizRəhimov I think it is better for you to use something ready like [ControlsFX PopOver](http://javadox.com/org.controlsfx/controlsfx/8.0.5/org/controlsfx/control/PopOver.html).